# Japanese Character filename turns unnamed-file on file upload php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am using a wordpress plugin (**Drag and Drop Multiple File Upload-Contact Form 7**) and I tried uploading japanese character filename ex. **サンプル.pdf** and when it is uploaded the filename changes to **unnamedfile.pdf.**

My PHP version is 7.3.11

I tried adding this code :

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

at the top of the plugin's php file. And it's not working.

I also tried adding this code:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');    
mb_http_output('SJIS');    
mb_http_input('UTF-8');       
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
```

but it's not working.

Comment: If you've tried something from a previous question that doesn't work, please just post a comment on that question. Don't post a new question stating that a previous question did not work.

Comment: @RussJ Sorry, I did just get the idea from the link i stated but it's a different issue that's why I posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem.
What I did is I commented a method for the plugin when creating the filename.

I found out the plugin was using functions from a file named dnd-upload-cf7.php.
This method seems to be the cause of the problem.

```
$filename = wpcf7_antiscript_file_name( $filename );
```

Just try this. Hope it works for you.